# Laravel: Adding a query parameter in the url of a form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

It's quite easy to open a form that will submit to a specific url:

```
echo Form::model($model, array('route' => array('user', $user->id)))
```

This will render something like this:

```
<form action="/user/1">
```

I want:

```
<form action="/user/1?q=54">
```

In other words, how can I change the form method to support the addition of a query parameter, in this case called "q"?

A simpler way of asking this would be: is there a way to generate a URL using Route's so as to include a query paramter?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add a hidden field named q and set it's value to 54?  That way it can be treated just like any other GET or POST variable.

Comment: It's just less tidy. I dont want to add whole field just to alter behaviour slightly.

Comment: Are you using POST or GET?

Comment: It's a POST, but does it really matter? Because I just want the "action" to include Q=whatever

Comment: Whether the form is GET or POST does matter - a GET form can't specify the GET params in the action using the question mark syntax, as it gets dropped as the form generates the URL from its inputs. As for your specific question though, I'm not sure. I say check out the `UrlGenerator` and `FormBuilder` code and see if they handle appending a query string to a URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the only answer I've found to this question is appending on the variable onto the URL like this:

```
echo Form::model($model, array('route' => array('user', $user->id.'?q=54')))
```

Though why don't you just use SEO friendly parameters like normal? So it would come out like

```
<form action="/user/1/54">
```

You can also use a route with parameters to make your URL's however you want them to look such as (I'm assuming the Q in your code means question:

```
Route::post('user/{id}/q/{q_id}', 'UserController@postQuestion');
```

Or

```
Route::post('user/{id}/question/{q_id}', 'UserController@postQuestion');
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved by adding a hidden field in the form and calling it from the controller.

```
{{ Form::hidden('_test', 'tags') }}
```

In the controller be sure to set this:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $test= Input::get('_test', 'default');
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method', '_test');
    // prevent from updating an inexistent field
...
```

---

Can't comment @Steve's answer cause of restrictions, will update in here:

It won't work because "Form::model" will process the value in "HTML::entities()", so

```
$id . "?test"
```

is going to be

```
1%3Ftest
```